# How to make column as constant field in PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am creating a table in `PostgreSQL`, I want to add some columns as constant columns like if I define there values as zero then `insert` and `update` could not change that column values.

More over that should also not show any error while using in `insert` or `update` query, is it possible?

**Example:**

table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbbt
(
  const_col integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  id integer,
  val text
)
```

queries:

```
insert into tbbt(const_col,id,val)  values(5,1,'ABC');
insert into tbbt(const_col,id,val)  values(6,2,'AVD');

update tbbt set val ='XZX', const_col = 3 where id =2;

select * from tbbt;
```

output:

it returns me

```
const_col   id  val
5            1  ABC
3            2  XZX
```

but i need

```
const_col   id  val
0            1  ABC
0            2  XZX
```

Comment: NOT NULL, check value = 0? But why constant columns?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: -http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a22fb/2

Comment: i have added example taken from ur fiddle, can u recheck it plz?

Comment: If you want to keep that column constant then whats the point of adding `const_col` column in `insert/update` script ?

Comment: i have added example taken from ur fiddle, can u recheck it plz? thanks @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ your example also helped me but insert update idea taken from answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can silently set the default value in a trigger:

```
create table test(id int, zero int);

create or replace function test_trigger()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    new.zero = 0;
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger test_trigger
before insert or update on test
for each row 
execute procedure test_trigger();

insert into test values (1, 1), (2, 2);

select * from test

 id | zero 
----+------
  1 |    0
  2 |    0
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use triggers for this purpose:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_constant_field_value()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    NEW.constant_column = 'constant value';
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
```

Example of `insert` trigger. Also you have to create same `update` trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_into_mytable
BEFORE INSERT
ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_constant_field_value();
```